# IIS Throws Config File Error - 0x8007000d when trying to deploy netcore2.0 App

Tags: iis, .net-core-2.0

I'm trying to deploy a netcore2.0 MVC app to IIS and keep getting the error above.
The file permissions are set correctly and I checked that the runtime is downloaded.
The error is as follows:

```
Module
IIS Web Core 

Notification
Unknown 

Handler
Not yet determined 

Error Code
0x8007000d 

Config Error
 

Config File
\\?\E:\Dev\test-deploy\web.config 


Requested URL
http://localhost:4231/ 

Physical Path

Logon Method
Not yet determined 

Logon User
Not yet determined
```

Following is my Config File (generated by vs code):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath=".\Coneckt.Web.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: 2833ed36-9a18-47b6-8f33-8998356796d9-->
```

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because the ApplicationHost.config or Web.config file contains a malformed XML element, you need to delete the malformed XML element from the ApplicationHost.config or Web.config file.

You can also refer to this link about how to deploy ASP.NET Core on IIS: [Host ASP.NET Core on Windows with IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Comment: I understand, but I can't find where my config file is malformed. I added my config file above for reference.

Comment: I not sure which part of your file has a problem, but Error 0x8007000d means URL rewriting module is missing or proper version is not installed, so you can try to install URL rewriting module via web platform installer.

Comment: I guess it is the URL rewriting that's the issue since I'm trying to run it on IIS 6 which doesn't seem to really support URL rewriting. I'll have to find a different solution.